# Locking Color-Only Jobs (Ricoh MP C3003)

Tags: printer, lock

We have a Ricoh MP C3003 but people have been printing their documents in color unnecessarily. So we have decided to lock the color function. Now there are still exceptions so we wanted to enable a code so that admins can print the color jobs for them. But with the option I've found it's an all or nothing lock (ie. once you enable lock both B/W and Color Jobs are locked), we want just color jobs to be locked.

Comment: This sounds a little like looking for a technical solution to a social problem.

Comment: @fixer1234 Unfortunately yes, with the amount that people are printing we could've upgraded 2-3 of our servers. Looks like we're going to have to play the mean sysadm and just lock the settings, hopefully our IT staff won't be bombarded with print requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create 2 drivers for the printer, one set to colour and the other to mono. Then make the mono printer available to everybody, and the colour printer to admins only. The printer has to be set from Printing Defaults (Printer Properties > Advanced tab) to ensure the settings will be the default. Setting them under Printing Preferences (under the General tab) only will not do the job. After setting Printing Defaults, check under Printing Preferences and adjust there is necessary.

Make sure you set permissions so people cannot change printer settings (under the security tab).

Another possibility is to use Print Management software. However, the cost of those might be more than some extra colour toner. For that matter, if many people need to print colour, your admins may be run off their feet.

Comment: Thanks, I've been researching the Print Management software and most of them just track usage or have settings that our current printer already has, so that might be out the window.